# Can't import custom R package with rpy2

Tags: python, r, macos, r-package, rpy2

I built an R package "myPackage" on Windows 10 / R 4.2.2

On my machine everything from building to using it in rpy2 works fine.

But when I try to use it in Python on a Mac:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import r

# Set encoding to avoid errors with rpy2
r('Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")')

# import custom R package
importr('myPackage', lib_loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library")
```

I get this error: `rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'myPackage'`

I am aware that this uses R Version 4.1.1

I also ran `library('myPackage')` in RStudio, and there was no problem.

I also double checked, that there is actually a directory "myPackage" in "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library".

So I think it has something to do with rpy2.

Any suggestions on how to import my package in rpy2 on a Mac?